# NSManagedObject insert and edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to implement a function to edit a some entry or made new entry if nothing exists. 
Here is the code

```
NSManagedObject *newConnection = [[NSManagedObject alloc] init];
if(_connection != nil) {
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Connection" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [request setEntity:entityDesc];
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@",  _connection.connectionID];
    [request setPredicate:pred];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if([objects count] > 0) {
         newConnection = objects[0];
    }
}
else {
    newConnection = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Connection" inManagedObjectContext:context];
}
```

_connection is the object, I'm getting from previous view if I'm trying to edit the connection. I'm getting also 1 object after `executeFetchRequest` but I'm getting an error `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` if I'm trying to assign objects[0] to newConnection. 
Is there a better way to do this? What am I doing wrong?

Solution:

`NSManagedObject *newConnection;` instead of `NSManagedObject *newConnection = [[NSManagedObject alloc] init];`

Comment: I'm getting an object from previous view if the connection should be edited. _connection is nil when I'm trying to add new connection

Comment: if you make, newConnection type id, and don't instantate anything in line one, does it still crash ?

Comment: Worth a read, to help you understand why the solution works https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html

Comment: @D051P0 you should make a real answer of your inline answer so people can find it later. The entire question can stay as a good example for misundertanding the ownerships in managed object contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NSManagedObject should be initiated with Entity:

> Creating a Managed Object Fundamentally NSManagedObject is an
>   Objective-C class like any other Objective-C class. Like various other
>   classes, NSManagedObject imposes some constraints on instance
>   creation. As described earlier, you must associate the new managed
>   object instance with the entity object that defines its properties and
>   with the managed object context that defines its environment. You
>   cannot therefore initialize a managed object simply by sending an init
>   message, you must use the designated
>   initializer—initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:—which sets
>   both the entity and context

newConnection can't have any Entity at the moment where it is being initialized. So the right way is to get only a pointer. And initialize it afterwards. I hope, I got this description right.

```
  NSManagedObject *newConnection;
        if(_connection != nil) {
            NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Connection" inManagedObjectContext:context];

            [request setEntity:entityDesc];
            NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@",  _connection.connectionID];
            [request setPredicate:pred];
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
            if([objects count] > 0) {
                 newConnection = objects[0];
            }
        }
        else {
            newConnection = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Connection" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good practice to check if there are any objects in the array you are trying to access.

```
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if([objects count]>0) {
    newConnection = objects[0];
}
```

Most probably in your case, there are no objects returned by your fetch request. And still you are trying to access the object at index 0. Hence the crash

Comment: I'm getting the object, but still get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Comment: where exactly are u getting the error? Even otherwise, it is a good practice to check the array before accessing its contents

Comment: on newConnection = objects[0];

Comment: are you sure that the objects array is not empty? did u place a breakpoint and check?

Comment: I have 1 Object in objects